# Loop through multiple list of sets

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a big list of sets. So I have splited that set into lists of 5 pairs.

```
datalist = [[{‘a’,’b’},{‘c’,’d’},{‘e’,’f’},{‘g’,’h’},{‘i’,’j}],[{another 5 items}]...]]
```

I would like to loop through each individual item and print key & value

```
Output
a  b
c  d
e  f
```

I have written this code but it’s not working for multiple lists of Dictionaries

```
For dic in datalist:
    For key,value in dic.items():
        Print(f”{key},{value})
```

Comment: Turn off "smart quotes" when posting code. You can't use curly quotes in Python.

Comment: Please make sure your code is properly formatted and reflects exactly what you have in your file. "smart quotes" are a syntax error, and keywords like `For` need to be in lowercase. Also, `it’s not working for multiple lists of Dictionaries` is not an adequate description of the problem. Please show what input you are using, what happens when you try the code, and explain how that is different from what you want to happen.

Answer (score 1):

You need nested loops. Then you can use set unpacking to pass all the set elements to `print()`.

```
for l in datalist:
    for s in l:
        print(*s, sep=',')
```

Comment: I tried that but getting this error AttributeError: ‘set’ object has no attribute ‘items’

Comment: Then your lists contain elements that aren't dictionaries. Some of them are sets.

Comment: But that's not what the question shows. I can only answer the question you ask.

Comment: Thank you Barmar

Comment: I have updated the datalist. I see it’s actually set not the dictionary

Comment: Sets don't have key-value pairs, they're just a collection of values.